# Why does manually implementing a hash tag give a performance boost to my queries?

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, nspredicate

In my model I set up an Entity (let's say Person) to have an attribute as string (called "name") and I put an index on it. If I do a lot of queries on my model the queries come out to be a performance drain. My query is a simple

```
  [ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %@", @"name", lPersonName ];
```

so I would assume that the index would do its work.

Then, if I calculate some simple hash tag and store that along with my entity, in an indexed integer attribute (called "hash"), and do a more narrow query the performance drain is gone. Like this:

```
[ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %d AND (%K == %@)",
                           @"hash", [ self calculateHashForName: lPersonName ],
                           @"name", lPersonName ];
```

Why is the index on the integer so much faster than an index on a string? Am I overlooking something? Is this a Core Data issue?

I can keep the solution with the hash tag, of course, but if I am overlooking something I would love to know about it sooner rather than later.

Comment: The type of the core-data store is SQLite, that could be important to know.

Comment: Seems reasonable to assume an index entity has a fast(er) lookup (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337238/questions-on-index-of-entity-in-core-data).

Comment: The question is, why is an index on a string not performant and an index on an integer is... I edited my question to make that more clear

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but gives clues to other optimisation possibilities: [Testing Core Data with big hierarchical data sets](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/testing-core-data-with-very-big.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two possibilities:

1. The size of the name strings are larger than the integers, so the storage space required is larger for the string index. Database performance is directly affected by storage size since the cost of a lookup is measured in disk seeks (ignoring caching for the moment), and the larger the data the more seeks requried
2. SQLite stores tables in B-trees, and can use the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY to look up a record with maximum efficiency with no extra index -- it's not clear (to me) from your code if the hash is being used as an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 1):

On a low level computers process integers natively, processors have an internal data type for integer but no internal data type for strings (in ARM and x86 land anyways).

```
4000000000 == -123456789
```

Can be processed by a computer in 1 instruction, while...

```
"Abcdefg" == "Abcdefzzzz"
```

Has to loop through the characters, taking several instructions.

This is fairly generalized, but it gets to the crux of the issue. In short, computers process integers quicker, and even though strings can be expressed as integers (binary bytes) they are a of a variable length which makes them more complex to process.

Comment: I understand that... I guess my question then would be: if you put an index on a string, why doesn't SQLite do some basic optimization with hash tags to optimize performance so that I don't have to? Maybe I should ask this on the SQLite mailing list?